# Book with Kangaroo warriors and demon tower

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading this book a long time ago, but I remember there being a Kangaroo warrior, a lizard guy, and a few humans.  I think they go into some sort of tower and deal with demons.  I think the people are trying to rescue a princess or a wizard, something like that (I know that narrows it down by a lot!)

I know it's not warriors of virtue, as that was the first result when searching for 'kangaroo warriors'.

Also, not a spell singer novel.  It came out in the mid 80s, and I believe had a tie in with other media as well.

Comment: If it was a comic, I'd suggest a misremembered Tank Girl. But your description sounds intriguing

Comment: @GeoffAtkins Oh that one is unforgettable. As is the theme song for the movie...which is now stuck in my head...thanks

Comment: The "Let's fall in love" scene... Cole Porter is bouncing in his grave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The novel in particular is the book *[Shadowkeep](http://crpgaddict.blogspot.com/2015/11/shadowkeep-novel-approach.html)* which was by Alan Dean Foster.  It was a tie-in to the videogame by the same name.  The Kangaroos were known as the Roo, with the Zhista (lizard people), Humans, and elven Thalidar.

The tower itself is over-run by monsters, lead by the demon Dal'Brad, who has imprisoned Nicomedon in crystal.

[image: Shadowkeep cover]

Comment: Huh. Never heard of that one. I may have to look it up.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Reread it when I rediscovered the book.  It's...okay, the game was originally for an Apple IIgs so the graphics look weird.

Answer (score 4):

A really wild guess, Allen Dean Foster's 1984 Spellsinger book, *[The Day of the Dissonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_of_the_Dissonance)*. The majority of the creatures in this world are humanoid animals with the eponymous spellsinger, Jon-Thomas Meriweather, being a rare human (humans exist, but they're considered kind of puny and lacking of physical advantages) who can do magic via his magic *duar* (sort of a magical guitar whose strings transcend time and space). There is a kangaroo, albeit one who works as a shopkeeper (the primary warrior of this book is the summon tigress, Roseroar). The lizard is less likely, as most of the lizards of the settings are unintelligent (and in fact serve as the beasts of burden and as a source of non-sapient meat). The setting has demons and towers, although I don't think this book has both at once.

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't that. I remember the spell singer books and it definitely wasn't this. I think it might have been a tie-in with a game or movie, but I can't be sure. It came out before I was born, so I think mid 80s.

Comment: so same author, similar characters, setting, but different magic mechanics.